# In placed reversed using only get methods

Tags: java, interface

Edge.java (interface)

```
public interface Edge {

  /**
   * get the first node of the Edge.
   * @return the first Node.
   */
  public int getFirstNode();

  /**
   * get the second node of the Edge.
   * @return the second Node.
   */
  public int getSecondNode();

}
```

EdgeImpl.java (implementation)

```
public class EdgeImpl implements Edge {

  private int node1;
  private int node2;


  public EdgeImpl(int node1, int node2) {
    this.node1 = node1;
    this.node2 = node2;
  }

  @Override
  public int getFirstNode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return node1;
  }

  @Override
  public int getSecondNode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return node2;
  }

}
```

first.java (What I need help in)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class first {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Edge> graph = new ArrayList<>();
    Edge a = new EdgeImpl(1, 2);
    Edge b = new EdgeImpl(3, 4);
    graph.add(a);
    graph.add(b);


  }
  public static void reverse(List<Edge> graph) {
    int count = 0;
    while(count < graph.size()) {
      int temp1 = graph.get(count).getFirstNode();
      int temp2 = graph.get(count).getSecondNode();
      graph.get(count).getFirstNode() = temp2;
      graph.get(count).getSecondNode() = temp1;
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }

}
```

The Edge interface is just two int values and we have two getters.

Let says we have a list that is like this [EdgeImpl(1,2), EdgeImpl(3,4)]

I want to make that listed into [EdgeImpl(2,1), EdgeImpl(4,3)]. Thats exactly what the reverse method will do.

EXCEPT

I CANT edit the interface nor the implementation so I cant add a set method and it has to be IN-PLACED.

My attempt fails because I cant use the get method to swap. I'm very confused on how I could swap both them

Any help?

Comment: Since, you don't have a setter method and also cant change the implementation. I think only way remains is reflection

Comment: How is `Edge` relevant at all, if your assignment is to reverse a `List`. At least that's the way you explained it. I recommend you ask your teacher for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the existing `EdgeImpl`, then create new ones!

I think what you meant by "in-place" is that you can't return a new list and you must modify the list passed in. You should be allowed to create new `EdgeImpl`s. If not, then that would involve reflection, which is not very trivial.

```
public static void reverse(List<Edge> graph) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < graph.size() ; i++) {
        int temp1 = graph.get(i).getFirstNode();
        int temp2 = graph.get(i).getSecondNode();
        EdgeImpl newEdge = new EdgeImpl(temp2, temp1);
        graph.set(i, newEdge); // this overwrites the element in the list at position i.
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this count as in-placed?

Comment: @ABC see paragraph 2 for why I think this counts as in placed.